# How to get total number of columns in stored procedure?

Tags: sql-server-2008

```
SELECT 
   CONVERT(VARCHAR, b.date, 105)    AS 'Date', 
   m.menucost * (Sum(bm.qty))    AS 'Total' 
FROM   
   billmaster b 
LEFT JOIN 
   billmenumapping bm ON bm.mapbillid = b.billid 
LEFT JOIN 
   menumaster m  ON m.menuid = bm.mapmenuid 
WHERE  
   b.date BETWEEN '2015/02/22' AND '2015/02/25'
GROUP BY
   b.Date, m.menucost
```

This code returns the following result:

```
Date         Total
-------------------
23-02-2015   40.00
22-02-2015   40.00
22-02-2015   1800.00
```

I need the output in a way where totals of date 22-02-2015 dates should be combined and only one result should be given as below. Sum of the total column should be done according to the respective dates.

```
Date         Total
--------------------
23-02-2015   40.00
22-02-2015   1840.00
```

Please help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
SELECT Date,SUM(Total) FROM
(SELECT CONVERT(VARCHAR, b.date, 105)    AS 'Date', 
           m.menucost * (Sum(bm.qty))    AS 'Total' 
    FROM   billmaster b 
           LEFT JOIN billmenumapping bm 
                  ON bm.mapbillid = b.billid 
           LEFT JOIN menumaster m 
                  ON m.menuid = bm.mapmenuid 
    WHERE  b.date between '2015/02/22'  and '2015/02/25'
    GROUP BY b.Date,m.menucost) TempTable
GROUP BY Date
```

Comment: Error. Msg 130, Level 15, State 1, Line 3
Cannot perform an aggregate function on an expression containing an aggregate or a subquery.